# parameter passing in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to use REST API in django for retrieve some data in json format.
When i hit this url:

> http://192.168.2.87:8000/locker/123/

It gives me output like this (from Database)

> {"id": 1, "locker_id": 123, "locker_user_name": "taimur"}

But if i want to get the output by passing the parameters like this

> http://192.168.2.87:8000/locker/?locker_id=123&locker_user_name=taimur&id=1

views.py

```
from postman, How can i do this??
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, get_object_or_404
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import Locker
from .serializers import LockerSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView


def locker_data_response(request, locker_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        locker_information = get_object_or_404(Locker, locker_id = locker_id)
        print(locker_information)
        locker_information_serialize = LockerSerializer(locker_information)
        print(locker_information_serialize)
        return JsonResponse(locker_information_serialize.data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('(?P<locker_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.locker_data_response, name='locker_data_response'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get them from the `request` object:

```
def locker_data_response(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    locker_id = request.data.get('locker_id')  # this will return None if not found
    locker_user_name = request.data.get('locker_user_name')
    locker_information = get_object_or_404(Locker, locker_id=locker_id)
    print(locker_information)
    locker_information_serialize = LockerSerializer(locker_information)
    print(locker_information_serialize)
    return JsonResponse(locker_information_serialize.data)
```

And the `url` will change to:

```
locker/$
```

[EDIT: Sorry, if you are using `drf` you should use `data` rather than `GET`]

[EDIT 2: If you want to use it like this, you will also need to change the  `url` and signature of the `view`]

[EDIT 3: Added the code in the correct place in view]

Comment: thank you for your quick response, I am confused                                               where i should write this 2 line of code? i mean i should write this in app's url.py and then pass this in urlpattern ?

Comment: This should go in your `views.py` to the `view` that is being called. (And you are welcome =D )

Comment: @TaimurIslam if you post your `view` I can show you.

Comment: @TaimurIslam glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

If your url is something like `domain/search/?q=haha`, Then you would use `request.GET.get('q', '')`.

`q` is the parameter you want, And `''` is the default value if `q` isn't found.

If you are instead just configuring your `URLconf`, Then your captures from the `regex` are passed to the function as arguments (or named arguments).

Such as:

```
(r'^user/(?P<username>\w{0,50})/$', views.profile_page,),
```

Then in your `views.py` you would have

```
def profile_page(request, username):
    # Rest of the method
```

Comment: use this example